# Get specific subarray using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"]
```

and I have another array of the same size:

```
var select = [0,1,1,1,0]
```

How can I get the array `fruits[select] = ["Orange", "Lemon", "Apple"]`, if this makes sense. This is something I can easily do in some other languages (e.g. R), but is this easily doable in JS?

Comment: Maybe by passing a loop in which if( i === 1) so enter the value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) passes its predicate an index, so:

```
fruits.filter((fruit, i) => select[i])
```

```js
let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
let select = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0];
let result = fruits.filter((fruit, i) => select[i]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you want to do it. However, something like below should work, granted the syntax might not be exactly correct.

```
var x = 0;
var selectedFruits = []
foreach(var bit in select)
{
    if(bit == 1)
       selectedFruits.Add(fruits[x])
     x++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to shift the values of `select` for filtering. This mutates `select` and needs a binding of this array.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"],
    select = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    selected = fruits.filter([].shift.bind(select));
    
console.log(selected);
```

Or just without binding but with `thisArg` of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"],
    select = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    selected = fruits.filter([].shift, select);
    
console.log(selected);
```

Comment: That's really clever! Not obvious what's going on, but really neat once you figure it out.

Comment: This does take quadratic time on arrays that are large enough on existing JS engines, mind.

Comment: @Ry-, just O(2n) (which is still O(n)), one for `fruits` and one for `select`. no quadratic time.

Comment: @NinaScholz: `shift()` takes time proportional to the size of the array. (V8 optimizes it to not move anything for small arrays, though.)